# Parsing HTML from my own page

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine

I've built a keyboard shortcut: select text, then ctrl+alt+m - to grey the text and insert the selected text into the comment box. BUT once I refresh, the grey part is gone; how do I save the revised grey text back into my db? I would like to save it when the user submits the comment.

The grey part is done using . I can't seem to find a way to parse the new data without using beautifulsoup, but beautifulsoup would require me to "fetch the same URL as the one making the request". Is there a better way to get the data from my own page?

Open to other suggestions that can achieve similar results.

I'm using python with webapp2 and jinja2.

The address of the page is: http://ykhblog1.appspot.com/blog/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood rightly then what you need is to

1. get the `innerHTML` of the elements that you are interested in
2. `post` this data to the server
3. then beautiful soup or other parsers can parse it directly as a string rather than having to fetch a URL (which wouldn't work anyway, because the text has only been highlighted on the client side)

However you may want to consider instead recording the changes the user makes to the page in some condensed format, e.g. "1-34-56' to say that the user highlights characters 34 to 56 of line 1. Otherwise you might end up passing a lot of html data back and forwards unnecessarily, and giving yourself a headache trying to parse it in the server side python code.